# Application Crashes: Message from debugger : Terminated due to memory issue swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title:nil, message: "Loading Data..", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let spinnerIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)
                spinnerIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50)
                //spinnerIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: 10.0, y: 5.0)
                spinnerIndicator.color = UIColor(hexString: "#256DA3")
                spinnerIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                spinnerIndicator.startAnimating()
                alert.view.addSubview(spinnerIndicator)

                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {

                     //var collection = PHAssetCollection()
                    //var assetsFetchResult : PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!

            for i in 2..<self.sectionFetchResults.count{
                autoreleasepool{
                 fetchResult = self.sectionFetchResults[i]

                    for j in 0..<fetchResult.count {
                        autoreleasepool{
                    collection = fetchResult[j] as! PHAssetCollection

                         assetsFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection , options: options)
                        if assetsFetchResult.count > 0 {


                           // DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    let loopIdx = assetsFetchResult.count
    //                        if(assetsFetchResult.count <= 300){
    //                            loopIdx = assetsFetchResult.count
    //                        }

                        for k in 0..<loopIdx {


                            //print(k)
                           // print(count)

                      let  asset  = assetsFetchResult[k]
                                    asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: optionss, completionHandler: { (info, _: [AnyHashable: Any]) in

                                            count = count + 1
                                     let  cgImgSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((info?.fullSizeImageURL)! as CFURL, nil)
                                        if cgImgSource != nil{

                                    let cfd = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(cgImgSource!, 0, nil)
                                    let  nsDic : NSDictionary = NSDictionary.init(dictionary: cfd!)
                                    let prop = nsDic as! [String : Any]
                                           autoreleasepool{
                                            if (prop[kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary as String] as? NSMutableDictionary) != nil{
                                                 self.event_name =  (prop[kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary as String] as! NSMutableDictionary)[kCGImagePropertyIPTCObjectName as String] as? String ?? ""

                                            if(self.event_name != ""){
                                                self.location_title = (prop[kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary as String] as! NSMutableDictionary)[kCGImagePropertyIPTCCountryPrimaryLocationName as String] as? String ?? ""
                                                self.person_Name = ((prop[kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary as String] as! NSMutableDictionary)[kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords as String] as? NSArray)?.firstObject as! String? ?? ""
                                                self.event_desc =  (prop[kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary as String] as! NSMutableDictionary)[kCGImagePropertyTIFFImageDescription as String] as? String ?? ""
                                                self.date = (prop[kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary as String] as! NSMutableDictionary)[kCGImagePropertyTIFFDateTime as String] as? String ?? ""
                                                let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()

                                            dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

                                            let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
                                            dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd hh:mm:ss"

                                            let getDate: NSDate? = dateFormatterPrint.date(from: self.date) as NSDate?
                                            self.date = dateFormatterGet.string(from: getDate! as Date)

                                                self.loc_long = (prop[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String] as! NSMutableDictionary)[kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude as String] as? CLLocationDegrees ?? 0.0
                                                self.loc_lat = (prop[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary as String] as! NSMutableDictionary)[kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude as String] as? CLLocationDegrees ?? 0.0
                                               insertSQL = insertSQL.appending("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO PhotosData (i_name, p_name, event_name, event_desc, event_date, location_Title, location_longitude, location_latitude,albumName) VALUES ('\(asset.originalFilename!)','\(self.person_Name)','\(self.event_name!)','\(self.event_desc)','\(self.date)','\(self.location_title)',\(self.loc_long),\(self.loc_lat),'\(collection.localizedTitle!)');\n")

                                               // self.insertInDatabase(query: insertSQL)
                                                print(count)
                                                if  count == c{
                                                  let check =  self.insertInDatabase(query: insertSQL)
                                                    if check {
                                                        DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                                    alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                                                        }
                                                    } else{
                                                           DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                                       alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                }
                                            }
                                                else {
                                                print(count)
                                                if  count == c{
                                                    var check = false
                                                   if insertSQL != ""{
                                                   check = self.insertInDatabase(query: insertSQL)
                                                    }
                                                    if check {
                                                           DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                                   alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                                        }
                                                    }else{
                                                           DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                                         alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                }
                                            }
}

}
```

I'm tying to fetch the metadata of images on load and as well as to save the fetched data in database.
The area of problem is mentioned above.
Could anyone help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to say from just looking at it. I would expect to see code that's causing you to load images rather than just metadata, but I don't see that in looking at your code. You do have 3 levels of nested loops. Have you put a count on the inner-most loop to see how many times it's executed? The number of iterations will grow dramatically with increases in the number of iterations in each loop. (The total number of iterations will go up with the cube of increases in all of your loop counts.)

Comment: Also, you should run your app using the Memory Instrument in Instruments and see what objects are occupying the lion's share of the memory. Usually the Memory Instrament quickly leads you to the "smoking gun" that's causing your problem.

Comment: Thank you @DuncanC for your comment . i figured out  that the for loop causes a problem so tell me feasible solution to get metadata of images. What should i do to fetch the metadata of 5000 images? I'll be thankful to you.

Comment: I mean, what is the feasible way to handle such a big process in my app with loading alert to user?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that, contrary to what Apple's documentation says, kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords is *not* a CFStringRef, but rather a dictionary.
I get a crash, too, at exactly the point where I want to use the result of retrieving kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords.